# Is there a way to create and deploy COM in .NET for Excel without registry entries?

Tags: .net, excel, com

There's an article here:
http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/

But on user pc it's not possible to modify registries, so is there possible to deploy com for excel without doing so ?

Update: seems not possible as addin, then is it possible if just using a com object.

Answer (score 3):

Although your question is lacking in detail, it sounds to me as though you might be looking for registration free COM. This excellent MSDN article explains the details: [Registration-Free Activation of COM Components: A Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)

if you wish to register an Excel COM add-in without writing to the registry then I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: seems not possible as addin, then is it possible if just using a com object with this free registration ?

Comment: registration free com works fine. But I still don't really know how you are invoking things. From VBA?

Comment: yes from vba custom defined functions, it's for wrapping flash and control it through excel functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Registration Free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) to make a COM component so that the component *itself* doesn't require any registry entries, but Excel itself basically provides all of its registration hooks via the registry, so no matter what I believe you will have to do *some* registry work, at a minimum. Otherwise, how would Excel even know that your component exists? However, you may be able to use HKCU instead of HKLM, so elevated privileges may not be needed if that is what you meant by "it's not possible to modify registries".

There is a similar question on [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/innovateonoffice/thread/cc08575d-3506-4a0f-a9e2-f23c2162ad38) with a little more detail about Excel and Registration-Free COM.